# iOS check network in AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, reachability

I have an app that relies on a network connection being available.  I have implemented reachability code to check for a network and/or host.  However, my question is this… if I do this check in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions can i just put up an alert indicating to the user that the app needs a network and then gracefully exit the app?  I have read mixed info on this and am unsure of how I can exit the app in a way such that Apple is happy and does not reject our app.

Answer (score 2):

If your app can't do anything at all unless there is a network connection, then show the alert view with no buttons.

But have your app deal with a network connection becoming available. If one becomes available, automatically dismiss the alert view and let the app run normally.

There is no need to force the app to terminate.

Update - based on some comments:

It would be much better to put the reachability check in the main view controller. Then it can be smart enough to deal with a lack of network. This handles no initial network as well as the network becoming unavailable as the app runs.

Comment: To add to this, if Apple tests your app and you exit it they see it as a crash and might reject your app because of it.

Comment: How?  Do I put up an alertView before I return YES from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?  When I did that, it appeared to continue execution and load my view, which then try too load from the internet.

Comment: Put the reachability check in your main view controller. Make it smart enough to display nothing (other than the alert view) if there is no network.

Comment: I'm gonna go with @rmaddy on this one, remember that you have to deal with losing the connection at anytime as well, so it's not sufficient to handle it only at didFinishLaunching time.

Comment: As an aside, if your app absolutely cannot function without an internet connection, that make that abundantly clear in the App Store description. Pay particular attention to this if your app will not be available free of charge.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you need to exit the app for the user?

Instead of an alert, why not just add a UIView with messaging explaining why your app won't work without a connection, and let the user exit themselves.

Exiting for the user is pretty aggressive and will probably look like your app crashed.

Answer (score 1):

Look for Reachability.h in https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability.

Once you've implemented Reachability.h:

```
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

reachability.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability *reachability) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"IsConnected"];
    NSLog(@"Network is reachable.");
};

reachability.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability *reachability) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"NO" forKey:@"IsConnected"];
    NSLog(@"Network is unreachable.");
};

[reachability startNotifier];
```

Each block will run every time the mobile connects or disconnects to the internet.

Hope it helps